# jQuery accordion open and close on click only

Tags: jquery

HOw can I make sure that the accordion opens and close only when you click on h3?
As it stands when you click on any of the h3 it closes straight after.
See the code below:

```
function accordion() {
    $('h3').click(function () {
        $('.box2').slideUp('normal');
        if ($(this).next().is(':hidden') == true) {
            $(this).next().slideDown('normal')
        }
    })
}
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(window).on("resize", function () {
        if ($(this).width() < 480) {
            accordion();
        } else if ($(this).width() > 480) {
            $('.box2').fadeIn(2000)
        }
    })
});
```

Comment: HTML mate? even better if you put it up on http://jsfiddle.net or http://jsbin.com

Comment: `slideToggle` would better suit me thinks

Comment: HTML code:                                                                  <h3>Service 1</h3>
<div class="box2"><p></p></div>
                        
<h3>Service 2</h3>
<div class="box2"><p></p></div>                     
               
<h3>Service 3</h3>
<div class="box2"><p></p></div>

Comment: NOTE: If you want multiple sections open at once, don't use an accordion -http://jqueryui.com/demos/accordion/

Comment: Nope, I just want to open and close on click only one section at the time...